# MySQL error Unknown column in field list when migrate the database to new server (Windows)

Tags: php, mysql

I chenge my db from one server to another and in debugging mode I have this error in Mysql database.

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'tb.adult_price' in 'field list']
```

I think this is how it starts

```
         $query="SELECT
                post_id,
                {$wpdb->prefix}st_tours.max_people,
                {$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta.adult_number+{$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta.child_number+{$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta.infant_number as total_booked
            FROM
                {$wpdb->prefix}st_tours
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta ON {$wpdb->prefix}st_tours.post_id = {$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta.st_booking_id
            AND {$wpdb->prefix}st_order_item_meta.st_booking_post_type = 'st_tours'
            WHERE
                1 = 1
            AND
```

---

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 0Ol3D_posts.*,CASE WHEN tb.adult_price > 0 and
tb.adult_price != '' THEN CASE WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on' AND 
tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() 
AND tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE() THEN CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) - ( 
CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) WHEN 
tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' THEN 
CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) 
* CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) ELSE tb.adult_price END WHEN tb.child_price > 
0 and tb.child_price != '' THEN CASE WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on' AND 
tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() 
AND tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE() THEN CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) - ( 
CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) WHEN 
tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' THEN 
CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) 
* CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) ELSE tb.child_price END WHEN tb.infant_price 
> 0 and tb.infant_price != '' THEN CASE WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on' AND 
tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() 
AND 
tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE() THEN CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) - ( 
CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) WHEN 
tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != '' THEN 
CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 
) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL) ELSE tb.infant_price END ELSE 0 END AS 
st_tour_price FROM 0Ol3D_posts LEFT JOIN 0Ol3D_term_relationships ON 
(0Ol3D_posts.ID = 0Ol3D_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( 
0Ol3D_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (470) ) ) AND 
0Ol3D_posts.post_type = 'st_tours' AND (0Ol3D_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR 0Ol3D_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY 0Ol3D_posts.ID ORDER BY 
RAND() LIMIT 0, 4
```

I search on my php files and I found the code:

```
    $query .=",CASE
        WHEN tb.adult_price > 0 and tb.adult_price != ''
         THEN
          CASE
            WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on'
            AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
            AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() AND tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE()
             THEN
                CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)
                    WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
                    THEN
                    CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.adult_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)

                ELSE tb.adult_price
                END

                WHEN tb.child_price > 0 and tb.child_price != ''
                THEN CASE
                WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on'
                AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
                AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() AND tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE()
                THEN
                CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)

                WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
                THEN
                CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.child_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)
                    ELSE tb.child_price
                    END
                WHEN tb.infant_price > 0 and tb.infant_price != ''
                THEN CASE
                WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule = 'on'
                AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
                AND tb.sale_price_from <= CURDATE() AND tb.sale_price_to >= CURDATE()
                THEN
                CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)

                WHEN tb.is_sale_schedule != 'on' AND tb.discount != 0 AND tb.discount != ''
                THEN
                CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) - ( CAST(tb.infant_price AS DECIMAL) / 100 ) * CAST(tb.discount AS DECIMAL)
                ELSE tb.infant_price
                END

                ELSE 0
                END AS st_tour_price";
```

I dont know much about SQL and databases..

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Without knowing the schema it's really difficult to help you.

Comment: check your tb table that filed adult_price have or not

Comment: You haven't shown us everything. Please [edit] your post. The variable `tb.adult_price` hints that a table in your query (named in a `FROM` or `JOIN`  clause) should have the alias `tb` in your query. It should look something like `FROM 0Ol3D_posts tb` or `FROM 0Ol3D_posts AS tb`  But I can't find anything like that in your question.

Comment: What the way to search if that column exists?

Comment: Propably something like SELECT * FROM tb.adult_price WHERE 0ol3d_posts ?? Causis not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about you set up in Windows... Something is not set up properly ( SQL-PHP version - IIS or Apache).... Try to change in config.php

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', false); --> define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Like you did in windows to see if your SQL error exists there as well.

If not trying to move database properly, that means not import it all immediately but with sql commands - open your export file with text editor and copy paste - so to be sure that database is installed properly.. After that check set up and your errors with delete.

That happened to me and was my server set up mistake.

Comment: Ok i will try and I let you know